# How to check for MDS vulnerability?

Tags: debian, security, firmware, vulnerability

I'm running Debian Buster (10.3) on a ThinkPad T420 (i5-2520M), current intel-microcode package is installed. To check for known CPU vulnerabilities I used the spectre-meltdown-checker script (https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker) which resulted in this output:

[image: Summary of spectre-meltdown-checker script]

According to the script all CVEs related to the Microarchitectural Data Sampling (MDS) vulnerability (which are specified in The Linux kernel user’s and administrator’s guide at: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html) are fixed on my system.

What makes me think is that `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds` leads to `Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable` which means that "The processor is vulnerable and the CPU buffer clearing mitigation is enabled." and "SMT is enabled".

How should the outputs of the tools be interpreted, or better asked, which tool can I trust?

EDIT:
This is the output with --paranoid option enabled:
[image: Summary with --paranoid option]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both tools agree; by default, `spectre-meltdown-checker` flags vulnerabilities as fixed even when SMT is an issue. If you add the `--paranoid` flag you should see a number of green boxes change to red.

On your setup, all the available fixes are applied on your system, apart from disabling SMT which is your decision to make. See also [Do I need to take action regarding my Microarchitectural Data Sampling (MDS) status?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541953/86440)

Which tool you trust most depends on how recent the tests are; pulling the latest `spectre-meltdown-checker` will usually ensure up-to-date tests there.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this clears things up. As you announced, --paranoid leads to some red fields but it also marks the status of CVE-2018-12207 as UNKNOWN. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: That’s strange, what does the detailed output from the 2018-12207 section say?

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot